# Can't find python scripts after sourcing

Tags: python, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

package.xml

```
<package>
 <description> knex_ros </description>
 <name> knex_ros </name>
 <author>jfstepha</author>
 <license>BSD</license>
 <url>http://ros.org/wiki/kinex_ros</url>
 <version> 0.0.0</version>
 <maintainer email="andre@note.note">andre</maintainer>

 <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
 <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
 <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
 <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
 <build_depend>robot_state_publisher</build_depend>
 <build_depend>differential_drive</build_depend>
 <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
 <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
 <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
 <run_depend>robot_state_publisher</run_depend>
 <run_depend>differential_drive</run_depend>
 </package>
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(knex_ros)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
  tf
  roscpp
  robot_state_publisher
  differential_drive
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES motor_control
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS ros_control roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
    scripts/knex_arduino_connector.py
    scripts/knex_scratch_connector.py
    scripts/range_filter.py
    scripts/range_to_laser.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

After I catkin_make under [ws], I did . [ws]/devel/setup.bash
When I run rospack find, I can find knex_ros, but when I rosrun knex_ros whatever.py, I got

```
~/catkin_ws/src/knex_ros$ rosrun knex_ros knex_arduino_connector.py
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named knex_arduino_connector.py below /home/andre/catkin_ws/src/knex_ros
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/andre/catkin_ws/src/knex_ros/scripts/knex_arduino_connector.py
```

I tried tab to show available executable from knex_ros package, it doesn't show anything. Other package under the same workspace work fine.

One weird thing I noticed happening along with not able to find executable is that I have to source devel/setup.bash every time I open a new terminal, and I didn't have to do this before.

update:

I ran catkin_make install and . install/setup.bash, and rosrun can find the executables.
Not sure why only running catkin_make, rosrun works for other package containing python scripts, but not for knex_ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192723/can%27t-find-python-scripts-after-sourcing/) by [mugenzebra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20084/mugenzebra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-09-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, you probably want to use the [recommended python style](http://wiki.ros.org/PyStyleGuide) for ROS.

Assuming these files are ros nodes:

```
scripts/knex_arduino_connector.py
scripts/knex_scratch_connector.py
scripts/range_filter.py
scripts/range_to_laser.py
```

the package directory style I follow for a ros package looks like this:

```
knex_pkg/
    CMakesLists.txt
    package.xml
    launch/ # roslaunch files go here
    msg/ # msg files go here
    nodes/ # installable python nodes go here
        knex_arduino_connector.py
        knex_scratch_connector.py
        range_filter.py
        range_to_laser.py
    src/ # this is where your python modules exported as libraries or used in your nodes go.
    urdf/ # urdf and xacro files go here -- basically your robot model stuff, if any.
    scripts/ # generally non-exported python scripts -- stuff that might be called to setup your package and code gen stuff
    srv/ # service descriptions go here
    __init__.py # only necessary if you want to use anything from the scripts directory in your package src and node files
    setup.py # more on this later
```

In your CMakesLists.txt you need to add a `catkin_python_setup()`([Handling of setup.py](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html)) line after your `find_package()` calls and before your service, message generation, and add messages calls:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(knex_ros)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
  tf
  roscpp
  robot_state_publisher
  differential_drive
)
catkin_python_setup()
...
```

`setup.py` is the [python distutils setup script](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html). It's where you describe the structure of a python package. The python style guide for ros is pretty specific in how python packages should be layed out. Any modules used should go under src. If you are like me, and like a clearly defined source tree structure with directories as package names, your setup.py will look something like this:

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['my_package'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    requires=['std_msgs', 'rospy', 'message_filters', 'gps_common', 'sensor_msgs']
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

In `setup_args` you are defining your package by calling `generate_distutils_setup`.

The `packages` argument is an array of package names. Use dot-delimited format (`my_package.subpackage`) if you wish to explicitly name more than one package. I generally just use one package root and let distutils figure it out from there, and I think this is the simplest practice.

The `package_dir` arg allows you to specify a source directory for a package name. If you have only one package, then you can omit the package name and give a relative path to the directory containing the modules for that package. If you follow the style guide, that directory will be `src`. If you have multiple packages in different source directories, you can specify them in this dictionary.

The `requires` arg is an array of python package names that are required by your package(s). In my example `setup.py` above, I use `std_msgs` so I've included it in the list. You will probably always have `rospy`. I don't think this is explicitly required for ros packages, but I think it is good practice to list them here.

The directory structure under `src` is important for the `setup.py` to work properly. If you have a package named `my_package` with submodules `my_submodule_a` and `my_submodule_b`, you need to set it up like this:

```
my_package/ # the root of the ros package
    setup.py
    src/
        my_package/ # here's your python module root
            __init__.py # put your python code for my_package here.
            my_submodule_a/ # I prefer directories for submodules, but some prefer just a python file named my_submodule_a.py instead
                __init__.py # this is your my_package.my_submodule_a source file.
            my_submodule_b/
                __init__.py # this is your my_package.my_submodule_b source file.
```

`catkin_python_setup` will allow you to use the modules in `src` in your executable node files by importing them from the `my_package` namespace. Similarly, service descriptions and msgs can be imported from this same namespace -- for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('my_package')

from std_msgs.msg import Header
from my_package.msg import MyMsg
import my_package.my_submodule_a

def run_my_node():
    init_node("my_package_node")
    spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_my_node()
```

Don't forget to mark your nodes as executable with `chmod +x nodes/my_package_node.py`!

I recommend setting up roslaunch launch files for your nodes, and parameterizing any arguments to them with the ros parameter server. You can set up any number of launch files and stack them together by using the `include` tag in other launch files. Then run them with `roslaunch my_package_name my_launchfile_name.launch`. It works out very nicely.

After you've done all that, update your installables in your `CMakesList.txt` and you should get a better result.

---

Originally posted by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) with karma: 207 on 2014-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mugenzebra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20084/mugenzebra/) on 2014-09-17**:
packages=['my_package], should it be packages=['my_package'] or packages=[my_package]? And in my case, if I understand about what this argument is for,  I should change my_package to knex_ros?

**Comment by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on 2014-09-17**:
`packages=packages['my_package']`

And yes, you should change it to `'knex_ros'`.

**Comment by [gariepya](https://answers.ros.org/users/19385/gariepya/) on 2015-02-11**:
Thank you so much for this very detailed guide! I had been trying to make my submodules copy to devel space for a long time

**Comment by [mr337](https://answers.ros.org/users/27943/mr337/) on 2016-09-19**:
2nd this, this saved my bacon after fighting with it! Thanks for the write up!!!!!

**Comment by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) on 2017-11-02**:
+1 forgot to mark the node as executable

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dumb thing to check - are all your python scripts executable?

---

Originally posted by [CatherineH](https://answers.ros.org/users/22373/catherineh/) with karma: 248 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jacob Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/23801/jacob-lambert/) on 2018-05-10**:
Thanks! bit strange to have to chmod +x your node.py files when coming over from python to c++..

**Comment by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) on 2018-10-30**:
This was it for me! Stupid mistake